# Tomcat running but gives 404 when trying to access my html, but instead shows tomcat's default page after installation

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I'm new to tomcat, I'm just trying to make a hello world application to get used to tomcat, but when I start my application and go to http://localhost:8080/helloweb/index.html it gives me a 404 error. If I go to http://localhost:8080/ then it takes me to the default webpage for tomcat. Please help, I've been trying to debug this forever but can't seem to find anyone else that is having this problem.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index Page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Entry Form</h1>

        <form name="Name Input Form" action="response.jsp">
            Enter your name:
            <input type="text" name="Name" value="" />
            <input type="submit" value="OK" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

NameHandler.java

```
package org.mypackage.hello;

public class NameHandler {
    private String name;

    public NameHandler() { 
        name = null;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/helloweb"/>
```

response.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:useBean id="mybean" scope="session" class="org.mypackage.hello.NameHandler" />
        <jsp:setProperty name="mybean" property="name" />
        <h1>Hello, <jsp:getProperty name="mybean" property="name" />!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Project Structure

```
My_Project_Root
 |-- pom.xml
 |-- nb-configuration.xml
 `-- src
     `-- main
         |-- java
         |   `-- com
         |       `-- example
         |           `-- my_project
         |               `-- sample_class.java
         |-- resources
         `-- webapp
             |-- META-INF
                 `-- context.xml
             |-- WEB-INF
             |-- index.html
```

Comment: As we can't access your localhost, source code will be necessary.

Comment: Of course, my bad. Just updated to include my source code.

Comment: How do you have it deployed?  Make sure the context root you use exactly matches the folder or filename.  The context.xml in the project is often ignored.

Comment: I made this project in netbeans and the context.xml was automatically generated. I'm deploying it through netbeans as well.

Comment: When you say the context root, do you mean the `<Context path="" />` in the context.html?

Comment: I'm not familiar with NetBeans, but in Eclipse there is a way to see what the context root is of the app.  Alternatively, you could do is deploy the .war file manually and see if you can get to it using the filename as the context root.

Comment: I've been looking into this for awhile now. Do I need to add a web.xml file?

Comment: Remove your useless `META-INF/context.xml` file. What is your `appBase` and where is your `index.html` file located? Actually... provide locations of all files.

Comment: Okay, I updated my question with my file structure. Why is the `META-INF/context.xml` useless? Should I remove that folder entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. I had to go into http://localhost:8080/manager/html and manually upload the .war file. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I was unable to find this anywhere in tomcat's documentation.

Comment: Well, nevermind, I actually did just find where it says this in their documentation.

Comment: ... or you could manually copy your .war file to Tomcat's `webapps` directory, which will do the same thing.